# Upgrading my Lenovo Legion 5 (500GB SSD) with additional 1TB

Tags: laptop, ssd, data-storage, upgrade

I have a Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05 Black with the following specs:

- Ryzen 7 4800H
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650
- 16GB
- 512GB
- 15.6" FHD 120Hz (82B5002AGE)

I have found out that it uses:

- SAMSUNG mzalq215halu-000l2 NVMe

Do you think that the M.2 SSD type is the right one to buy?

If yes, is it safe to upgrade it myself as the battery is located inside and cannot be removed until I open the laptop?

Here is the opened laptop:
[image: Opened Laptop]

Comment: It's safe yes. As long as it's off and not plugged in there is no power going anywhere

Comment: @Irsu85 I think I made a mistake it is impossible actually. I have to change the SSD on the left down side completely and replace it. not possible to add

Comment: I see two SSD slots actually. One covered by one of the metal plates (M.2) and one SATA in the bottem left. You can add one in the bottem left, although you will need a SATA ssd then.

Comment: Yes I did. but without the SATA ssd as there is one M.2 also just above the SSD sata